# Hash 16-bit integer to a 256-bit space efficiently

Tags: c++, algorithm, hash, glsl, shader

It sounds weird to be going *bigger*, but that's what I'm trying to do.  I want to take the entire sequence of 16-bit integers and hash each one in such a way that it maps to 256-bit space uniformly.

The reason for this is that I'm trying to put a subset of the 16-bit number space into a 256-bit bloom filter, for fast membership testing.

I could use some well-known hashing function on each integer, but I'm looking for an extremely efficient implementation (just a few instructions) so that this runs well in a GPU shader program.  I feel like the fact that the hash input is known to be only 16-bits can inform the hash function is designed somehow, but I am failing to see the solution.

Any ideas?

---

EDITS

Based on the responses, my original question is confusing.  Sorry about that.  I will try to restate it with a more concrete example:

I have a subset S1 of n numbers from the set S, which is in the range (0, 2^16-1).  I need to represent this subset S1 with a 256-bit bloom filter constructed with a single hashing function.  The reason for the bloom filter is a space consideration.  I've chosen a  256-bit bloom filter because it fits my space requirements, and has a low enough probability of false positives.  I'm looking to find a very simple hashing function that can take a number from set S and represent it in 256 bits such that each bit has roughly equal probability of being 1 or 0.

The reason for the requirement of simplicity in the hashing function is that this hashing function is going to have to run thousands of times per pixel, so anywhere where I can trim instructions is a win.

Comment: Could you clarify how the identity function does not work for what you are trying to do? It is fast.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Typically bloom filters use a set of hashes to test for membership. In a perfect situation, the OP could find `n` hash functions which fill the 256 bit space and have the fewest number of collisions (ideally none, but this is not possible here). That said, there exist `2^16` 16-bit integers, so the identity function would not map into these 256 bits since `256 < 2^16` (i.e. 1-bit to mark an integer as in the set).

Comment: @RageD The question is not about identifying n hash functions, it asks for one, and does not make clear how the identity is not a satisfying solution.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I added that for completeness since he is using a bloom filter. I suspect OP got caught up in thinking the space of 16-bit integers is 16-bits and not `2^16`. Assuming I understood the OP correctly, he has up to `2^16` integers which he wants to hash into a 256-bit _bit vector_. If OP is really holding `2^256` bits in memory, he should instead use the first `2^16` bits (identity function as you suggested) as an injection and treat each bit as a simple boolean value (0 or 1).

Comment: It does say "sequence of 16-bit integers".  Look at SHA-1. I have heard SHA-1 can be done in a GPU.  If you need a number of hashes, prepend a 16-bit counter to your data and run thru SHA-1 once per counter value.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: That probably wouldn't be **uniformly**. Then again, we don't have a _measure_ so there's no definition of uniform anyway. Simply said: `x << 240` is quite uniform when the measure is `x-y` but not at all when the measure is `x^y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you multiply (using `uint32_t`) a 16 bit value by prime (or for that matter any odd number) `p` between 2^31 and 2^32, then you "probably" smear the results fairly evenly across the 32 bit space. Then you might want to add another prime value, to prevent `0` mapping to `0` (you want each bit to have an equal probability of being `0` or `1`, only one input value in 2^256 should have output all zeros, and since there are only 2^16 inputs that means you want none of them to have output all zeros).

So that's how to expand 16 bits to 32 with one operation (plus whatever instructions are needed to load the constant). Use four different values `p1` ... `p4` to get 256 bits, and run some tests with different `p` values to find good ones (i.e. those that produce not too many more false positives than what you expect for your Bloom filter given the size of the set you're encoding and assuming an ideal hashing function). For example I'm pretty sure `-1` is a bad p-value.

No matter how good the values you'll see some correlations, though: for example as I've described it above the lowest bit of all 4 separate values will be equal, which is a pretty serious dependency. So you probably want a couple more "mixing" operations. For example you might say that each byte of the final output shall be the XOR of two of the bytes of what I've described (and not two least-siginficant bytes!), just to get rid of the simple arithmetic relations.

Unless I've misunderstood the question, though, **this is not how a Bloom filter usually works**. Usually you want your hash to produce an exact fixed number of set bits for each input, and all the arithmetic to compute the false positive rate relies on this. That's why for a Bloom filter 256 bits in size you'd normally have `k` 8-bit hashes, not one 256-bit hash. `k` is normally rather less than half the size of the filter in bits (the optimal value is the number of bits per value in the filter, times `ln(2)` which is about 0.7). So normally you *don't* want the probability of each bit being 1 to be anything like as high as 0.5.

The reason is that once you've ORed as few as 4 such 256-bit values together, almost all the bits in your filter are set (15 in 16 of them). So you're looking at a lot of false positives already.

But if you've done the math and you're happy with a single hash function producing a variable number of set bits averaging half of them, then fair enough. Or is the double-occurrence of the number 256 just a coincidence, because `k` happens to be 32 for the set size you have chosen and you're actually using the 256-bit hash as 32 8-bit hashes?

[Edit: your comment clarifies this, but anyway `k` should not get so high that you need 256 bits of hash in total. Clearly there's no point in this case using a Bloom filter with more than 16 bits per value (i.e fewer than 16 values), since using the same amount of space you could just list the values, and have a false positive rate of 0. A filter with 16 bits per value gives a false positive rate of something like 1 in 2200. Even there, optimal `k` is only 23, that is you should set 23 bits in the filter for each value in the set. If you expect the sets to be bigger than 16 values then you want to set fewer bits for each element, and you'll get a higher false positive rate.]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Having not implemented a bloom filter before, I've underestimated the importance of multiple hash functions.  You've given me a lot to look over, but given the flawed question, I think you answered it the best.  Accepted

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is some confusion in the question as posed. I will first try to clear up any inconsistencies I've noticed above.

OP originally states that he is trying to map a smaller space into a larger one. If this is truly the case, then the use of the bloom filter algorithm is unnecessary. Instead, as has been suggested in the comments above, the identity function is the only "hash" function necessary to set and test each bit. However, I make the assertion that this is not really what the OP is looking for. If so, then the OP must be storing `2^256` bits in memory (based on how the question is stated) in order for the space of 16-bit integers (i.e. `2^16`) to be smaller than his set size; this is an unreasonable amount of memory to be using and is highly unlikely to be the case.

Therefore, I make the assumption that the problem constraints are as follows: we have a 256-bit **bit vector** in which we want to map the space of 16-bit integers. That is, we have 256 bits available to map `2^16` possible different integers. Thus, we are not actually mapping into a larger space, but, instead, a much smaller space. Similarly, it does appear (again, as previously pointed out in the comments above) that the OP is requesting a single hash function. If this is the case, there is clear misunderstanding about how bloom filters work.

Bloom filters typically use a set of hash independent hash functions to reduce false positives. Without going into too much detail, every input to the bloom filter runs through all `n` hash functions and then the resulting index in the bit vector is tested for each function. If all indices tested are set to `1`, then the value **may** be in the set (with proper collisions in all `n` hash functions or overlap, false positives will occur). Moreover, if any of the indices is set to `0`, then the value is **absolutely not** in the set. With this in mind, it is important to notice that an entirely saturated bloom filter has no benefit. That is, every query to the bloom filter will return that the item is in the set.

**Hash Function Concerns**

Now, back to the OP's original question. It is likely going to be best to use known hashing algorithms (since these are mathematically difficult to write and "rolling your own" typically doesn't end well). If you are worried about efficiency down to clock-cycles, implement the algorithm yourself in the appropriate assembly language for your architecture to reduce running time for each hash function. Remember, algorithmically, hash functions should run in `O(1)` time, so they should not contribute too much overhead if implemented properly. To start you off, I would recommend considering the modified bernstein hash. I have written a version for your specific case below (mostly for example purposes):

```
unsigned char modified_bernstein(short key)
{
  unsigned ret = key & 0xff;
  ret = 33 *  ret ^ (key >> 8);
  return ret % 256; // Try to do some modulo math to keep it in range
}
```

The bernstein method I have adapted generally runs as a function of the number of bytes of the input. Since a `short` type is `2` bytes or `16-bits`, I have removed any variables and loops from the algorithm and simply performed some bit twiddling to get at each byte. Finally, an `unsigned char` can return a value in the range of `[0,256)` which forces the hash function to return a valid index in the bit vector.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I don't think this answers the question I intended to ask, I've updated my original question to be more clear.

Comment: @amoffat: I see your edits. Any "good" hash function should distribute its output uniformly (note:  [SUHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUHA_(computer_science)) principle). That is why I left you with an implementation of a simple/known algorithm. More importantly, why are you constrained to a single hash function? You will lose much of the mathematical benefit of a bloom filter when you do this [Bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter). I can link the papers if you prefer academic literature to the informal wikipedia refs. Also, in the end, you may saturate your bloom filter.